# Jquery Ajax Request sometimes not returning data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

On button click data is sent always . But jquery ajax sometimes not returning data. I don't understand the reason behind this.

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
    url:'assets/get_cart_small_info.php',
    type: 'get',
    data: 'getsmallcart=true',
    beforeSend:function(){
            $('.cart_info').html('<img src="img/ring.gif">');
    },
    success: function(data){
    setTimeout(function () {
            $('.cart_info').html(data);
         }, 2000);
         },

       error:function(){
          $('.cart_info').html('<strong>Oops!</strong> Try again');
                           }
            });

            })
```

Currently creating a shopping cart where on every click cart value increases by 1. Then on next click it returns 2, then on another it returns 3 and so on... But sometimes it is not returning anything on clickin. Now then when I click again it returns 5. That means the previous value is sent already but it didn't show at that time and showing it on next click along with the next value. Please help!

Comment: the return value would show in firebug from the console view. Are you using that?

Comment: no.. I dont know what is that..

Comment: Did you try alerting return value in success function?

Comment: It is a firefox add-on. pretty essential stuff for debugging jQuery. http://getfirebug.com

Comment: ok.. but is anything wrong with my jquery ajax code?

Comment: yes the console is showing this "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."...what does this mean? and how to do that??

Comment: You need to use the higher version of Jquery.

Comment: You do realize you have a two second delay in there from when the data is returned until it's displayed? Also, try setting cache to false

Comment: And there is no click handler, does the page reload everytime you click ?

Comment: no why the page will reload? then I wouldn't be using ajax